# Python - Setting JSON data from itunes in Data Frame with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to Python and I am facing, what a I believe to be, a fairly simple problem with Json and Pandas.

Unfortunately it seems that my brain stopped working, so I would appreciate your help.

I want to analyse reviews on itunes from the game Super Mario, and I want to do it with JSON.

I want to retrieve the comments and all the information that comes along, and I want to have it as a Data Frame so I can start my analysis.

Link: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/page=1/json

My code:

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

requestpost = requests.get('https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/page=1/json')
r = json.loads(requestpost.text)
r

dict_keys= r['feed'].keys()

df = pd.DataFrame(r['feed'] , columns = [list(dict_keys)])
df
```

**Output:** 
`author   entry   updated rights  title   icon    link    id`

I just get the columns and no data inside each column.

I am following the book Python for Data Analysis, I have read the documentation and went through countless examples. I do not understand what is the problem.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Best regards

**Solution**

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/page=1/json')
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
data = json_data['feed']['entry']
pd.json_normalize(data=data)
```

Comment: can you add expected output because the json has each value as a dictionary

Comment: @komatiraju032 I am not sure I follow. I want to have the data for each of the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you get your desired output the following way:

```
import json
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

response = requests.get('https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/customerreviews/id=1388411277/page=1/json')
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
data = json_data['feed']
json_normalize(data=data)
```

json_normalize returns a dataframe.

Comment: I got returned a simple row, but after reading the @Nathan Thomas comment, I added the following to your code and it worked just fine:

data = json_data['feed']['entry]

Comment: For `pandas` >= v1.0 `json_normalize` is in the `pandas` namespace, so should be used as `pd.json_normalize`.  It's no long in `.io.json`.

Answer (score 0):

From your data it looks like you have multiple keys within the first key. For example:

```
r['feed']["author"]
```

output:

```
{'name': {'label': 'iTunes Store'},
uri': {'label': 'http://www.apple.com/uk/itunes/'}}
```

So you will need to filter down a bit more to get your desired output

Comment: I complemented what you said with @flandersen's code. It seems I still do not fully understand JSON. Thank you for the insight.